# Filling the space supressed with the data below in report builder

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

Good day,

I am fairly new to report layouts and i require some assistance on Report Builder 3, i have developed my report and there is a section the gets supressed on a certain condition, i would like to move the data below into the space that is left vacant when the data is supressed.

Thanks,

Dean

Comment: Please add sample data or screenshot what you want to get and also give us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to hide it.

1. Create a new report
2. Right-click, add List
3. Put the first part (before the bit you want hiding) of the report into the new list box
   [image: FirstBitOfReport]
4. Right-click on the (Details) group and group it on 1 (this makes it just show once - no repeating per page of something)
   [image: GroupOnOne]
5. Right-click on the same group and click "Add Group - Adjacent After)
6. Group this on 1 as well
   [image: NewGroupOneOne]
7. Insert a rectangle into the new textbox that shows
8. Add the items to this rectangle you wish to hide
9. Repeat steps 5-8 to add a new element below the bit you wish to hide
10. Should look like..
    [image: Layout]
11. Right-click on the middle row group and select Group Properties
12. In the Visibility box, put your expression to determine when to show or hide the stuff you want to hide
    [image: Visibility]

When you run the report and the criteria for hiding are met then the row group will not generate and the bits below will move up (so no empty whitespace). It also makes it much easier to manage your report in the future as you know everything in that group will be hidden based on your criteria.